# Converting JSON to Value with Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

How can I convert JSON to Value or Data(Haskell) with Data.Aeson or get AST with arbitrary JSON if I don't know beforehand the structure of JSON?

Answer (score 4):

The [`decode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode) function does this.

```
decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a
```

Here are some examples, taken directly from the [`Data.Aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) module documentation:

```
>>> decode "{\"foo\": 123}" :: Maybe Value
Just (Object (fromList [("foo",Number 123)]))

>>> decode "{\"foo\": [\"abc\",\"def\"]}" :: Maybe Value
Just (Object (fromList [("foo",Array (fromList [String "abc",String "def"]))]))
```